Where are the two different spinor representations of the Lorentz group in the Poincare representation?
When studying the finite dimensional irreducible representations of the Lorentz group, we come across spinors, which can be thought of as objects in the $(j_1,j_2)$ representation. We have Weyl spinors transforming in the $(1/2,0)$ or $(0,1/2)$ representations, and a Dirac spinor lives in the $(1/2,0) \bigoplus (0,1/2)$ representation.
But when we study the unitary reps of the Poincare group (via Wigner's little group method), we end up using the quantum numbers $(m,s)$ to label the representations. My question is, where is the information about the existence of two different kinds of spinors, and where is the information about the two spin quantum numbers of the corresponding Lorentz representation, within this Poincare representation?

I think you are getting confused between the Poincare group and the Lorentz group. The spinor representations you have mentioned are finite dimensional, but all non-trivial unitary representations of the Poincare group are infinite dimensional.

They're two different representations that act on two different objects - the finite dimensional Lorentz reps act on the fields; Poincare reps act on the fields realised as operators on the Hilbert space of the theory (via the Wightman axioms). My point being they should still contain the same information about the particle/particle type. So how exactly does one find the existence or signature of the two different spinor representations of the Lorentz group in the Poincare rep? They essentially embody the two different chiralities of spin 1/2 species - so where's chirality in the Poincare rep?

For massive particles, the left- and right-handed fields mix due to the EOM, but helicity is still useful. Since helicity is frame-dependent for massive particles, so the (m,1/2) representation contains both the left- and right-handed fields in it.

Oh I think I understand a bit better now; Could you link to a reference for this?

I would look at chapter 8 in Schwartz's QFT book at this short pdf (pg 3-4): https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://physicstravelguide.com/_media/advanced_tools/group_theory/genial-massiv-und-masselos-besser-erklaert.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiOh4O_j5aJAxWwLTQIHcx0LsAQFnoECBcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3merb-jCosZsddIJ7wdUOu

Weyl spinors are massless, Dirac spinors are not.  The little group for massless particles is ISO(2) whereas the little group for massive particles is SO(3).  That's what distinguishes them.
For Weyl spinors, the chirality is given directly by what you call the $s$ quantum number.  For Dirac spinors, we can project onto the different chiral states using the projection operators $\psi^\dagger(1\pm\gamma_5)\psi$, where $\psi$ is the Dirac field operator.

Perhaps you misunderstood my question; I've added more to it in the other comment

I think I did understand it.  You want to know how Weyl spinors and Dirac spinors are different in the unitary reps of the Poincare group.  They're different because they transform according to different little groups.

I'll edit my answer to include information about chirality.

No I was not asking how Weyl and Dirac spinors are differentiated - clearly they have two different little groups like you say. But if we consider a massive particle in a Dirac spinor, it contains information about the two different chiralities in it. My question was how do you seek out this information in the Poincare rep?

See my edited answer.  The two different chiral projection operators (plus and minus) are how you get the two different chiral states.
